# How to prevent jQuery onScroll firing after scrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, onscroll

I'm having troubles using both onScroll and scrollTo. 
I have two DIV's placed next to each other and synchronized scroll between them. Meaning when one of them scrolls, another scrolls to exact place. Made like this:

```
function syncCompareScroll(e) {
var $other;
var $this = $(this);
if ($(this).hasClass('left-doc')) {
    $other = $(".right-doc");
} else {
    $other = $(".left-doc");
}
console.log("scroll called " + $(this).attr("class"));

clearTimeout(compareScrollTimer);
compareScrollTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    $this.off('scroll');
    $other.off('scroll');

    var cutoff = $this.scrollTop();
    var elemOffset;
    var $currElement = $this.children().first();

    $this.find("[name ^= 'sect']").each(function () {
        elemOffset = $(this).offset().top;
        if ((elemOffset + cutoff - 100 - 30) > cutoff) {
            $currElement = $(this);
            return false;
        }
    });
    var elemToScroll = $other.find($("[name = '" + $currElement.attr("name") + "']"));
    $other.scrollTo(elemToScroll, 0, {axis: 'y'});

    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.on("scroll", syncCompareScroll);
        $other.on("scroll", syncCompareScroll);
    }, 50);
}, 200);}
```

also I have button which scroll both DIV's to needed location:

```
$(".next-change").click(function () {
                if (index < changedSectionsNames.length) {
                    index++;
                    var name = changedSectionsNames[index];
                    var $leftChange = $(".left-doc [name = '" + name + "']");
                    var $rightChange = $(".right-doc [name = '" + name + "']");
                    if ($leftChange.hasClass("added")) {
                        $rightChange = $(".right-doc [name = '" + $leftChange.find("del").attr("name") + "']");
                    }
                    if ($rightChange.hasClass("added")) {
                        $leftChange = $(".left-doc [name = '" + $rightChange.find("del").attr("name") + "']");
                    }
                    $(".left-doc").off('scroll', syncCompareScroll);
                    $(".right-doc").off('scroll', syncCompareScroll);
                    $(".diff .content .left-doc").scrollTo($leftChange, 200, {axis: 'y'});
                    $(".diff .content .right-doc").scrollTo($rightChange, 200, {axis: 'y'});
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".left-doc").on("scroll", syncCompareScroll);
                        $(".right-doc").on("scroll", syncCompareScroll);
                    }, 50);
                }
            });
```

The problem is when buttons onClick finished syncCompareScroll also called. How do I prevent it from calling on button click?

UPDATE
html is simply 2 DIV's with structure like this:

```
<div>
    <div class='left-doc>
        <p name='sect1'>text</p>
        .... so on
    </div>
    <div class='right-doc'>
        <p name='sect1>another text</p>
        .... so on
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle example. As you can see after pressing next DIV's scroll to needed p's. But after scrollto finished, syncCompareScroll started, and it breaks position of left side.

http://jsfiddle.net/m7ad36ju/

Comment: can you fiddle the query ?

Comment: post the html too please

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a variable in the global scope called noSyncCompareScroll.  Set it to false by default.  When you call the .next-change onClick event, set noSyncCompareScroll to true.  In the syncCompareScroll, check the value of noSyncCompareScroll.  If it's true, set it to false and exit the function; otherwise run syncCompareScroll like normal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This is the first thing i've tried. And no luck. syncCompareScroll start AFTER .next-change click event finished.